# Relative computational burdens of the matrix and raster in R

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm surprised to discover that a matrix I've created from a large raster allegedly takes up a stomping 35k times more memory than the parent. This code demonstrates:

```
> # comparison with R's built-in volcano data
> object.size(volcano)
42656 bytes
> object.size(as.matrix(volcano))
42656 bytes
> # comparison with my data
> class(region_utm)
[1] "RasterLayer"
attr(,"package")
[1] "raster"
> dim(region_utm)
[1] 7297 7297    1
> object.size(region_utm)
12128 bytes
> region_mat = as.matrix(region_utm)
> dim(region_mat)
[1] 7297 7297
> object.size(region_mat)
425969872 bytes
```

`object.size(region_utm)` is certainly giving a wild underestimate, as 12,128 bytes is insufficient to contain 53m values, even factored, particularly as 87% (46m) are unique values (according to `length(unique(region_utm))`).  Not sure then how to get a realistic memory estimate..

However plotting the raster *is* significantly quicker than working with the matrix.  But I've always thought of matrices as roughly equivalent to rasters without spatial data slots, but I must be missing an important difference between these data structures.  Grateful for clarification on what could explain this memory disparity.  I use matrix workflows a fair bit and need to understand their limitations.

---

**Edit:** anticipating a request for an `str()` report:

```
> str(region_mat)
 num [1:7297, 1:7297] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
> summary(as.vector(region_mat))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
   -1.7    21.3   118.1   135.5   236.9  1020.0 1266438 
> str(region_utm)
Formal class 'RasterLayer' [package "raster"] with 12 slots
  ..@ file    :Formal class '.RasterFile' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  .. .. ..@ name        : chr "/private/var/folders/kh/vlbqbp3n29lcvp491zbrnpl80000gn/T/R_raster_robinedwards/raster_tmp_2014-02-09_164243_1484_10601.grd"
  .. .. ..@ datanotation: chr "FLT8S"
  .. .. ..@ byteorder   : Named chr "little"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "value"
  .. .. ..@ nodatavalue : num -1.7e+308
  .. .. ..@ NAchanged   : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ nbands      : int 1
  .. .. ..@ bandorder   : Named chr "BIL"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "value"
  .. .. ..@ offset      : int 0
  .. .. ..@ toptobottom : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..@ blockrows   : int 0
  .. .. ..@ blockcols   : int 0
  .. .. ..@ driver      : chr "raster"
  .. .. ..@ open        : logi FALSE
  ..@ data    :Formal class '.SingleLayerData' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  .. .. ..@ values    : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ offset    : num 0
  .. .. ..@ gain      : num 1
  .. .. ..@ inmemory  : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ fromdisk  : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..@ isfactor  : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ attributes: list()
  .. .. ..@ haveminmax: logi TRUE
  .. .. ..@ min       : num -1.73
  .. .. ..@ max       : num 1020
  .. .. ..@ band      : int 1
  .. .. ..@ unit      : chr ""
  .. .. ..@ names     : chr "layer"
  ..@ legend  :Formal class '.RasterLegend' [package "raster"] with 5 slots
  .. .. ..@ type      : chr(0) 
  .. .. ..@ values    : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ color     : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ names     : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ colortable: logi(0) 
  ..@ title   : chr(0) 
  ..@ extent  :Formal class 'Extent' [package "raster"] with 4 slots
  .. .. ..@ xmin: num 180386
  .. .. ..@ xmax: num 394918
  .. .. ..@ ymin: num 1879673
  .. .. ..@ ymax: num 2103691
  ..@ rotated : logi FALSE
  ..@ rotation:Formal class '.Rotation' [package "raster"] with 2 slots
  .. .. ..@ geotrans: num(0) 
  .. .. ..@ transfun:function ()  
  ..@ ncols   : int 7297
  ..@ nrows   : int 7297
  ..@ crs     :Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slots
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr "+proj=utm +zone=16 ellps=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84"
  ..@ history : list()
  ..@ z       : list()
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `object.size` has an `S4` method.  Someone with more knowledge (and intelligence :-( ) than I may know for certain.

Comment: No it is that the bulk data is kept in file by raster for that object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I'm almost certain that `object.size` doesn't do what you want on `S4` objects.   Take a peek at the code for `cgwtools::lssize` . Here's part of what I wrote, with a lot of help from other SO contributors:

```
fb4 <- function(x) {
               if (isS4(x)) {
                      slots <- setNames(slotNames(x), slotNames(x))
                      lapply(lapply(slots, slot, object=x), fb4)
                      } else object.size(if(is.list(x)) unlist(x) else x)
                    }
            fb4(object)
            }
    sizes<-sapply(items,function(k) sum(unlist(s4gonebyte(get(k))) ),simplify=FALSE)
```

That's a recursive dive into `S4` slots and subslots.

Comment: Sounds like you're right. Is this also why R can't save a raster using `save()`? Shame there's no obvious detail of this limitation in the documentation.

Comment: @geotheory depends where you look:  try `raster::stackSave` and `writeRaster`, among other raster to/from file tools.

Comment: I know writeRaster but it seems less efficient for storing or reading back in. Will try stackSave